# Who Bowled the Fastest Ball in Cricket till now?

Tags: cricket

Who bowled the fastest ball in cricket? I got to know that Shoaib Akhtar is not the right answer there is someone else who bowled a faster ball than him.

Answer (score 2):

[Guinness World Records lists Akhtar as the bowler of the fastest ball of all time](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/fastest-bowl-of-a-cricket-ball):

> The highest electronically measured speed for a ball bowled by any bowler is 161.3 km/h (100.23 mph) by Shoaib Akhtar (Pakistan) against England on 22 February 2003 in a World Cup match at Newlands, Cape Town, South Africa.

The rest of the quote from that page is *very* significant though:

> Quote from World Cup communications director: "ICC has always said there is not enough uniformity in the various speed guns around the world for any one performance to be designated official". However many believe this to have been the fastest ball bowled.

i.e. you *cannot* compare measurements from different matches against one another, due to *systematic* differences between the equipment used. There are claims that [Mohammad Sami bowled balls at both 164 km/h and 162.3 km/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Sami#Bowling_action); the 164 km/h ball was ruled out due to "faulty speed measurements on the speed meter", but there is no clear explanation available as to why the 162.3 km/h ball was ruled out.

**TL;DR**: nobody actually knows because there isn't an accurate means of measuring.

Answer (score -1):

There is no perfect,actual or true equipment which can measure the speed of ball correct or accurately in all environment.
While the fastest speed ball bowl by PAKISTANI cricketer player "Shoaib Akhter" with the speed of 161.3km/h.
During the World Cup  group A match between "Pakistan " and "England" at "Newlands stadium, Cape Town, South Africa", 22 feb 2003 .
Second fastest ball was bowl by AUSTRALIAN cricketer "Shaun Tait", during the 5th ODI at "Lord's" cricket ground , "London",3 jul 2010 with the speed of 161.1km/h.
so there is slightly speed difference but still Shoaib Akhter is fastest bowler in cricket history.